# program stops after reading procedure (delphi)

Tags: delphi, pascal, bubble-sort

My program stops to read anymore lines and ends the program after this procedure like its 'end.' after it (but its not) :

```
  Procedure BubbleSort;
  var i, j : integer;
  begin
    for i := 0 to count - 1 do begin
      for j := count - 1 downto i do
        if (together[j] > together[j - 1]) then
          Swap(together[j - 1], together[j]);
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: What is `count`, what value does it have?

Comment: i dont know exactly but a lot...like 50 maybe

Comment: Don't guess! Put a break point on the first `for`loop and let the debugger tell you.

Comment: the value is 28 exactly

Comment: And what happens when you step through the code with F8 after the breakpoint.

Comment: The cause may be something quite unrelated to this procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the problem is the out of bounds array access. You access index -1. Avoid this by changing the outer loop to:

```
for i := 1 to count - 1 do begin
```

I suggest that you enable range checking so that you can learn about out of bounds array access by way of informative runtime errors.

Comment: it worked thanks a lot....but i dont really understand what you wrote up there...could you explain to me a little more ?

Comment: When i is 0, the end of the j loop is 0. And so you access index j-1. Which is, well you can do the math.

Comment: Oops - typed too slow...Seems I can edit my comments but can't delete them. If i is 0 at the beginning of the outer loop, then j will be set to i-1 = -1 at the end of the inner loop. what will happen when you try to access together[-1] ?

Comment: @Filip And you set *range checking* and *overflow checking* on in your project options/compiler (exact menu items vary with Delphi version). They should always be on so that you get the actual errors when and where they occur (instead of dependant errors later on). Not many programs need or must have these options off.

Comment: @JanDoggen I'd go so far as to say that no program should have these options off.  I have a few applications that gain important performance from disabling range checking but, when I do it, it is always locally with compiler directives and only around those methods that are in the performance bottleneck.  Something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4998442/327083  but always also conditional on `{$IFNDEF DEBUG}` so that errors are caught during any development if things change.