# How do I check whether an array contains a particular value?

Tags: delphi

how do I correctly write this ?:

```
If number is different from Array[1] to Array[x-1] the begin......
```

where number is an integer and array is an array of integers from 1 to x

Comment: I'm sure I've advised you not to use 1-based array indices. Allow me to repeat the advice.

Comment: Also, `Array` is not a valid variable name in Delphi.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I already told Filip that at least once before too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594762/program-stops-after-reading-procedure-delphi

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'm sure Filip will notice that when he tries to compile his code...

Comment: It was just an exaple i am not using either Array as a name of an array or 1-based array

Comment: i was just hoping there exists something like....if number <> myarray[0] to myarray[x-1] then begin

Comment: Make a function that checks whether an item is contained in an array. For instance, in my code base I would write: `if not TArray.Contains(arr, value) then ...`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe you want to do something if `number` is not found in the array `MyArray`. Then you can do it like this:

```
NoMatch := True;
for i := Low(MyArray) to High(MyArray) do
  if MyArray[i] = number then
  begin
    NoMatch := False;
    Break;
  end;

if NoMatch then
  DoYourThing;
```

You could create a function that checks if a number is found in an array. Then you can use this function every time you need to perform such a check. And each time, the code will be more readable. For example, you could do it like this:

```
function IsNumberInArray(const ANumber: Integer; 
  const AArray: array of Integer): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Low(AArray) to High(AArray) do
    if ANumber = AArray[i] then
      Exit(True);
  Result := False;
end;

...

if not IsNumberInArray(number, MyArray) then
  DoYourThing;
```

If you use a old version of Delphi, you have to replace `Exit(True)` with `begin Result := True; Exit; end`. In newer versions of Delphi, I suppose you could also play with stuff like generics.

Comment: @Jens Except your code is very different from Andreas'

Comment: If you'll use the `begin result := true; break; end;` version, you'll also need to move `result := false;` at the beginning of the function. You could let it at the bottom if you'll use `exit;` in place of `break;`.

Comment: @Bozzy: Correct. Or use `Exit` instead of `Break`.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same question and solved it like this:

```
if value in myArray then
  ...
```

But as I needed to compare with specific values, I simply did:

```
if value in [0, 1, 2, 3] then
  ...
```

Answer (score 6):

You could also write a Generic version, however you can't use generics with stand-alone procedures, they need to be bound to a class or record.  Something like the following

```
unit Generics.ArrayUtils;

interface

uses
  System.Generics.Defaults;

type
  TArrayUtils<T> = class
  public
    class function Contains(const x : T; const anArray : array of T) : boolean;
  end;

implementation

{ TArrayUtils<T> }

class function TArrayUtils<T>.Contains(const x: T; const anArray: array of T): boolean;
var
  y : T;
  lComparer: IEqualityComparer<T>;
begin
  lComparer := TEqualityComparer<T>.Default;
  for y in anArray do
  begin
    if lComparer.Equals(x, y) then
      Exit(True);
  end;
  Exit(False);
end;

end.
```

usage would be

```
procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if TArrayUtils<integer>.Contains(3, [1,2,3]) then
    ShowMessage('Yes')
  else
    ShowMessage('No');
end;
```

Should work with parameters like `TArray<integer>` or `array of integer` as well as constant arrays (shown) - and you could add many other methods to the class, such as `IndexOf` or `Insert`...

From Delphi 10.3 you can omit the `<integer>` due to type inferencing so would look like `TArrayUtils.Contains(3, [1,2,3])`.

Comment: Needed something for TArray<TGUID> and this works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Seems slower than Andreas' version.