# Is there a way to turn compiler switch directives to the current default state (instead of just ON or OFF)?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney, dcc32

For Delphi compiler directives, is there a way to turn a switch directive to its "current global default state"?

I have read the documentation page at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Delphi_compiler_directives, but it explains only how to turn switch directives on or off. My code contains several places with this construct (meant to avoid hints for a particular section of code):

```
{$HINTS OFF}
  // ... some code ...
{$HINTS ON}
```

However, this turns hints (back) *on* afterwards, which is *not* what I want when I do e.g. a release compilation with hints suppressed globally (using for example the -H- option to the dcc32.exe command-line compiler).

I would want something like this:

```
{$HINTS OFF}
  // ... some code ...
{$HINTS DEFAULT}
```

Does that exist?

Comment: Unfortunately, most of the [compiler directives](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Compiler_Directives_(List)_Index) (including `{$HINTS}`) DO NOT provide a `DEFAULT` option ([`{$WARN}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Warning_messages_(Delphi)) does, for instance).  For many directives, you can use [`{$IFOPT}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/IFOPT_directive_(Delphi)) to help accomplish what you want (see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4998442/65863)), however `{$HINTS}` does not work with `{$IFOPT}`, so you are basically SOL in this case.